# Finding shortest non-zero vector $x$ satisfying $Ax=0 \pmod q$

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Let $n$, $m$, and $q$ be positive integers (with $m > n$), and $A$ be a matrix over $\mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times m}$. Using *Mathematica*, I want to find the shortest non-zero vectors $x \in \mathbb{Z}_q^m$ such that:

$$Ax=0 \pmod q$$

Note: By "shortest," I mean the vector with the smallest Euclidean norm. I'm not sure if this vector is unique. If it's not, I want a list of vectors with smallest Euclidean norm.

---

**Example:**

Let: $n=2, m=3, q=7, A = \left(\begin{matrix} 2 & 1 & 6\\ 1 & 3 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$. Then, the following vectors are solutions to

{1,1,3} $\quad$ Norm = $\sqrt{11}$

{3,3,2} $\quad$ Norm = $\sqrt{22}$

{2,2,6} $\quad$ Norm = $\sqrt{44}$

{5,5,1} $\quad$ Norm = $\sqrt{51}$

{4,4,5} $\quad$ Norm = $\sqrt{57}$

{6,6,4} $\quad$ Norm = $\sqrt{88}$

Therefore, the vector {1,1,3} is the shortest solution.

---

**PS:** I used an exhaustive search to find the above solutions. My approach takes a long time for even small choices of $n$ and $m$, say $n=2, m=8$. Please offer an approach which can at least find solutions for such small parameters.

**Edit:** As Michael suggested in a comment, I demonstrate the "exhaustive search" code I used. I'm not proud of it at all, as I just wrote the code to find an example for this question.

```
A = RandomInteger[6, {2, 3}];
x = {a, b, c};
Table[
  If[Mod[A.x, 7] == {0, 0}, Print[{x, x // Norm}]], 
    {a, 0, 6}, {b, 0, 6}, {c, 0, 6}]
```

Comment: You might show the code you tried -- perhaps it can be made efficient.  Users are much more likely to try out your problem if they can cut and paste a starting point.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the code snippet. It does not use Mathematica's built-in functions like `Solve` or `FindMin`. It's nothing more than an exhaustive search, and that's why it takes a long time to find a solution for even relatively small parameters.

Comment: Yes that would take a long time. :)  If you thought of `Solve`, you should have tried it!  Another tip: Don't use `Print` to accumulate you results.  `Table` will accumulate them; then `DeleteCases[table, Null, Infinity]`, gets rid of the `Null`s; then perhaps `Flatten`.  Better yet, learn about `Reap`/`Sow`.

Comment: (1) You are working in a ring that really does not have a notion of length. Why is a rock-bottom smallest in Euclidean norm result needed?

Comment: (2) One can get small results using lattice reduction. This unfortunately does not force values to be nonnegative. All the same, a usable vector might appear. In a run of your example I have `mat = {{2, 3, 2}, {2, 6, 1}}`. Then it turns out that `{4,3,2}` is the null vector of interest (though see (1) above-- I do not know why it is of interest). It appeas in the following lattice reduction. `In[35]:= LatticeReduce[
 Join[NullSpace[A], 7*IdentityMatrix[Length[A[[1]]]]]]

Out[35]= {{-2, 2, -1}, {1, -1, -3}, {4, 3, 2}}`

Comment: (3) If you can tolerate using instead the l_1 norm, then integer linear programming can be brought to bear on this. See [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7517/) for an ICMS 2006 that has explicit code for exactly such problems. If you have to go with l_2 then it is harder than ILP.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Your point (1) is totally correct. Actually, when I looked back at the problem, I noted that $x \in \mathbb{Z}_q^m$ is wrong, and I should have written $x \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ instead. I didn't change the OP, since that would render the answers incorrect. Since $x \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ will allow for both positive and negative vector components, I think `LatticeReduce` will provide the "shortest" answer, as your point (2) says. Please correct me if I', wrong.

Comment: You are wrong, but close. `LatticeReduce` is guaranteed to find a vector that is "short" (in Euclidean norm) in a particular sense. But it is not guaranteed to be shortest. In practice, it tends to be close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to approach this is to use the Null space of the matrix `a`, which is a basis for all elements `x` such that `a.x=0`. For the OPs problem, this can be done by first finding the null space:

```
a = {{2, 1, 6}, {1, 3, 1}};
n = First[NullSpace[a, Modulus -> 7]]

{5, 5, 1}
```

Now, observe that `a.x=0` is true exactly when `a.(c*x)=0`, so it is possible to list all the answers (mod 7) to this problem by

```
Mod[# n, 7] & /@ Range[7]

{{5, 5, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {6, 6, 4}, {4, 4, 5}, {2, 2, 6}}
```

To find the one with smallest norm, apply the norm to each element,

```
Norm /@ (Mod[# n, 7] & /@ Range[6])

{Sqrt[51], Sqrt[22], Sqrt[11], 2 Sqrt[22], Sqrt[57], 2 Sqrt[11]}
```

which gives the same answer as the OP found by search.

More generally, the `NullSpace` of `a` is a collection of $m-n$ vectors, and it will be necessary to search over all linear combinations of these $m-n$ vectors (mod $q$) for the one with the smallest norm. While this may still be large, it is certainly smaller than search over $m$ dimensions as in the brute force approach.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Solve` helps a bit.  If `vars` is the list of variables, then

```
Solve[A.vars == ConstantArray[0, n], vars, Modulus -> q]
```

finds all solutions in terms of parameters `C[1]`, `C[2]`, etc. depending on the dimension of the solution space.

Another bottleneck is computing the values of the general solution at all possible combinations of values for the parameters `C[i]` modulo `q`.  The possible combinations can be computed with

```
Tuples[Range[0, q - 1], n]
```

where `n` is the number of parameters `C[i]`.  The result is certainly reasonably fast for the small values of `m`, `n`, `q` mentioned in the question.

Finally `Nearest` will return the shortest nonzero vector (the zero vector having been deleted).

```
findSols[q_, A_] := 
 Module[{m, n, vars, x, sol, vals, params, vecs},
  {n, m} = Dimensions@A;
  vars = Array[x, m];
  sol = vars /. First @ Solve[A.vars == ConstantArray[0, n], vars, Modulus -> q];
  (* Print@sol; *) (*optional output*)
  params = Union@Cases[sol, _C, Infinity];
  (* Print@params; *) (*optional output*)
  vals = Transpose @ Tuples[Range[0, q - 1], Length@params];
  vecs = DeleteCases[
    Mod[#, q] &@ Transpose[sol /. MapThread[Rule, {params, vals}]], 
    ConstantArray[0, m]];
  Nearest[vecs, ConstantArray[0, m]]
  ]
```

Example in OP:

```
A = {{2, 1, 6}, {1, 3, 1}};
findSols[7, A] // Timing
(* {0.000675, {{1, 1, 3}}} *)
```

Additional example with $m=8$.  (Over 117000 solutions, still less than a second.)

```
SeedRandom[2];
A = RandomInteger[6, {2, 8}]

findSols[7, A] // Timing
(* {{5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 2, 6, 5}, {2, 1, 5, 5, 0, 0, 6, 4}} *)
(* {0.289682, {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}}} *)
```

Note that for `q = 17` there will be over 24,000,000 solutions -- I killed the kernel when it went past 20GB.